# MySQL: Combine DISTINCT values from columns b & c GROUP BY column a

Tags: mysql, database

This is driving me batty. I've got the following basic table structure:

```
+-----+-----+-----+
| YEAR| ID1 | ID2 |
+-----+-----+-----+
| 2012| 103 | 105 |
| 2012| 110 | 114 |
| 2013| 103 | 110 |
| 2013| 114 | 120 |
| 2014| 122 | 103 |
+-----+-----+-----+
```

What I need is a list of distinct values from columns ID1 and ID2 grouped by results by column YEAR. To spice it up, the lowest YEAR must be shown per distinct value. Result table should look like this:

```
+-----+-----+
| Year|  ID |
+-----+-----+
| 2012| 103 |
| 2012| 105 |
| 2012| 110 |
| 2012| 114 |
| 2013| 120 |
| 2014| 122 |
+-----+-----+
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: We're not here to do your work for you, please show what you've tried. Then we'll help you get it working. Hint: use a `UNION` in a subquery to get ID1 and ID2 into a single column.

Comment: @Strawberry Because 2014 is the lowest year for the distinct value 122. It's not the ids that should be min, it's the year.

Comment: @Barman I don't think that any of my attempts would have helped in any way to find a solution. I was on the completely wrong track, simply because UNION for some obscure reason did not cross my mind at all. I appreciate your concern that users post questions on stackexchange in lieu of thinking about the problem first. But I do think that it is quite obvious that if an OP goes to some lengths to illustrate the question (i.e. format table structures etc.) he is at the end of his wits rather than lazy. So my thanks go out to jpw and Strawberry who actually made an effort to help.

Comment: @Tomm Don't thank me - I'm with Barmar on this one. He gave you a big hint. I was way off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `union all` to build a relation (`year, id`) and apply `min(year)` to that and `group by` `id`:

```
select min(year) min_year, id
from (
    select year, id1 id from your_table
    union all
    select year, id2 id from your_table
) x
group by id
```